# linear regression model beta estimate

Tags: regression, estimation

> Suppose we want to estimate $\beta$ by minimizing $L(\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\beta x_i)^2+\lambda|\beta|$, where $\lambda$ is a fixed positive constant. Calculate the estimate.

How would I calculate $\beta$ in this scenario?

where the linear regression model is $$y_i = \beta x_i + \epsilon _i; i = 1,..., n$$

Comment: Take the derivative $\dfrac{dL}{d\beta}$ and trying to get it equal to $0$ would be a start.  Clearly it need not be continuous at $\beta=0$ so you should probably try positive and negative $\beta$ separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider first $\beta>0$.
First order condition with respect to $\beta$ would imply
$$\frac{\partial L(\beta)}{\partial\beta}=0 \Rightarrow -\sum^{n}_{i=1} 2(y_i-\beta x_i)x_i +\lambda=0\Rightarrow \sum^{n}_{i=1}(y_i-\beta x_i)x_i=\lambda/2\Rightarrow  \beta=\frac{-\lambda/2+\sum^{n}_{i=1}y_ix_i}{\sum^{n}_{i=1}x^2_i}$$
So your optimal estimate is 
$$\beta^*=\frac{-\lambda/2+\sum^{n}_{i=1}y_ix_i}{\sum^{n}_{i=1}x^2_i}$$
if $\beta<0$ then 
$$\beta^*=\frac{\lambda/2+\sum^{n}_{i=1}y_ix_i}{\sum^{n}_{i=1}x^2_i}$$

Comment: You may need to extend this to cases where $\left| \sum_i y_ix_i \right| \lt \lambda/2$.  You could also mention that the second derivative is $2 \sum_i x_i^2$, i.e. positive

Comment: @ Henry: You are correct. A positive second derivative would imply that it is a minimum. But I skipped the verification part. What about the other cases?

Comment: I suspect that when $\left| \sum_i y_ix_i \right| \le \lambda/2$ you should be considering $\beta^*=0$ as otherwise it will be the wrong sign.